# Requests sharing a session with browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, python-webbrowser

Alright this is an interesting question I recently had: If I am using requests, is/could there be a way to share a session *with* the browser? For example, you POST login data to a website on your Python application, and you are logged in on your browser. Not looking for help with my code or anything, more curious as to if this could be achieved.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563335/how-do-i-load-session-and-cookies-from-selenium-browser-to-requests-library-in-p.