# How to get a JSON response from a Google Chrome Selenium Webdriver client?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Currently I have Selenium hooked up to python to scrape a webpage. I found out that the page actually pulls data from a JSON API, and I can get a JSON response as long as I'm logged in to the page.

However, my approach of getting that response into python seems a bit junky; I select text enclosed in `<pre>` tags and use python's `json` package to parse the data like so:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
json_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('pre').get_attribute('innerText')
json_response = json.loads(json_text)
```

The only reason I need to select within `<pre>` tags at all is because when JSON appears in Chrome, it comes formatted like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

And the only reason I need to do this inside selenium at all is because I need to be logged into the website in order to get a response. Otherwise I get a 401 and no data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can find the `pre` element and get it's text, then load it via `json.loads()`:

```
import json 

pre = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text
data = json.loads(pre)
print(data)
```

Also, if this does not work as-is, and, as suggested by @Skandix in comments, **prepend `view-source:` to your url**.

---

Also, you may avoid using `selenium` to get the desired JSON data and transfer the cookies from `selenium` to `requests` to keep "staying logged in", see:

- [How do I load session and cookies from Selenium browser to requests library in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563335/how-do-i-load-session-and-cookies-from-selenium-browser-to-requests-library-in-p)

Comment: 1. Good to know that the `<pre>` method works (although `.text` is definitely nicer than my approach `.get_attribute('innerText')`)...

Comment: 2. TIL about `requests`'s cookies support. I managed to avoid another page load of this 7MB angular app from hell, shave a few seconds off my script run time, and write cleaner code. Thanks!

Comment: for those of you who have trouble with firefox autoformating the json-response into a table and changing the source: add **"view-source:"** in front of your url. Then you can continue using find-by-tag "pre".

Comment: 2023 use: driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'pre').text